# How to set env with laravel artisan to have two different database connections (local/remote)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I looking for setup a multi-environment project using Laravel3 but I dont understand the command to set the environment.

I see here: http://laravel.com/docs/artisan/commands
The command is:

```
php artisan foo --env=local
```

I already used artisan and bob with success, what I can't undertand the **foo**, I try to change to my project name but always the same output: "Sorry, I can't find that task."

If I try:    php artisan --env=local

That will return: "You forgot to provide the task name."

Anybody can help? Thanks for your time.

**[edit]** With the answers now I can understand better and improve my question:

I have a project with those folders created: http://d.pr/i/5nZS
With that in mind, I need to set my local env as development and production as production. So, I can do that with any variation of the command "php artisan --env=local" or I need to add on my public/.htaccess "SetEnv LARAVEL_ENV development"?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, how I solved my question:

First I didn't need the command `php artisan migrate --env=local`, I just need set on my virtualhost: `SetEnv LARAVEL_ENV development`.

Second, as William Cahill-Manley say, I need to work on application/paths.php, the $environments. I've used it before but the wrong way. In my case, I solve with that:

```
$environments = array(
    'development' => array('http://localhost/project*', '*project/*'),
    'production' => array('http://project.com', 'http://*.project.com')
);
```

My problem was because my code before was like that:

```
$environments = array(
    'development' => array('http://localhost/project*', '*project*'),
    'production' => array('http://project.com', 'http://*.project.com')
);
```

And because the second element of development array, in the production server always will be in development.
Thats because the url on development be `http://project/` and on production be `http://project.com/` or `http://user.project.com/`

See, the *project* will force in all envonriments be development by the asterisk/wildcard.

Answer (score 14):

"Foo" is whatever command you want to run. E.g. for migrations:

```
php artisan migrate --env=local
```

Another thing you can do is add your computers hostname to [this array](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/paths.php#L26)

For example, if my local computer name is 'Effinity.local' I could do

```
$environments = array(
    'local' => array('http://localhost*', 'Effinity.local'),
);
```

Then you do not need to specify the environment, just:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: So, on my local I need set:
"$ php artisan migrate --env=development"
And on production server:
"$ php artisan migrate --env=production"
With that and my array like this: https://gist.github.com/4557659
And also with my config folders configured like that: http://d.pr/i/5nZS

This will work? I tried but still seems not work, what I also tried is with "SetEnv LARAVEL_ENV development" what's almost working but I need a little more time to try again. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Foo is a task name , try to create this file in the task folder, there are some other task which is predefine for example migration etc.

```
<?php 
    class foo_task {
    public function run(){
            echo 'this is foo';
        }
    } 
?>
```

then when you run the command,it will run the code inside the run function.

```
php artisan foo --env=local
```

Comment: Yeah, thats what I imaginate before but with "php artisan foo --env=local" this will run the task just when the env is local, right? What I really need is set the whole project as a local or development and with that make my config folder (d.pr/i/5nZS) work and connect the  correct database host.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting up a name-based virtual host for your web application first:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "__PATH TO YOUR SERVER ROOT___/project/public/"
    ServerName project.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/project-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/project-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then add project.dev to your hosts file `/private/etc/hosts` as follows:

```
127.0.0.1 project.dev
```

Don't forget to flush the DNS cache afterwards:

```
$ dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Then amend the $environments array found in `[project root]/path.php` (the applications/path.php file you mentioned does not exist) back to what it was. The original *.dev wildcard will pick up the .dev at the end of the url you provided.

```
$environments = array(

    'local' => array('http://localhost*', '*.dev'),

);
```

Then create a directory within `applications/config/` called `local`, place within the new directory a file called `application.php`. The configuration given in this file will override the configuration set by the corresponding configuration files and settings/values given in the parent of the `local` directory you have created.